# Informix ODBC Driver Installation through Powershell

Tags: informix, powershell-4.0

I want to install informix odbc connector in my system using powershell.

Please check the below code which I have tried already.

```
$toolsDir = (Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)
$Src64path = Join-Path $toolsDir 'installclientsdk.exe'
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $Src64path -ArgumentList '/S /v/qn' -PassThru 
Write-Host 'Informix Driver is Installed for 64bit'
```

This code is giving the installation results that the driver is installed but when I am checking in control panel it's not giving the desired results.

Comment: "This code is giving the installation results that the driver is installed" - but you're not checking the return code from the installer? However unless anyone knows in the Informix installer (and it's been ten years since I've worked with Informix) I'm not sure if we can help you. You might have to debug the install process yourself, e.g. check for any logs it has left behind, or watch what it's doing in Process Monitor for any errors, or something else. Does it work from a non-PowerShell console?

Comment: tried through cmd prompt but powershell or cmd silent install is almost the same i have never seen a case in which it works in cmd prompt and will not work in powershell. My basic requirement is to install driver silently so that i can automate it to different server.

Comment: ODBC (and the rest of components of CSDK) can be installed in "Slient" mode if you have the correct response / properties files for the installer. The parameters you mentioned in your post (/S /v /qn) are for old versions of CSDK. Have look at  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.cpi.doc/ids_cpi_018.htm

Comment: tried with the mentioned link its still the same.